# Random sequence of integers in $\{1, 2, \dots, n \}$ which is "everywhere probably increasing" - how long can it be?

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, extremal-combinatorics

Let $D=(d_1,d_2,\dots,d_k)$ be a sequence of correlated random variables. $D$ is "everywhere $r$-probably increasing" if the event $d_j > d_i$ has probability $\geq r$ for all $j > i$.

Fix $r \geq 1/2$. How long can a random sequence of integers in $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ be, and still be $r$-probably increasing?

Perhaps surprisingly, the answer is not $O(n)$. For example, the random sequence which is $(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)$ with 50% chance and $(1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3)$ with 50% chance is everywhere $1/2$-probably increasing. It's easy to generalize this to get, when $r=1/2$, a sequence of length $n^2$. With a bit more work, when $r=a/b$, one can get a sequence of length $\sim n^{b/a}$.

I conjecture the answer is $O(n^{1/r})$. But I can't find any relevant papers, and frustratingly, I can't even prove *any* upper bound for any $r<1$.

Comment: If $r$ is greater than $1-1/n$, you can't have a sequence longer than $n$ by the union bound, since you would get a positive probability that $d_1 \lt d_2 \lt ... \lt d_n \lt d_{n+1}$, which is impossible.

Comment: My answer now has matching upper and lower bounds, estabilishing $n^{1/(2r-1)+o(1)}$ as the best possible.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I adapt an argument from [this blog post of mine](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2013/10/29/a-spectral-theory-proof-of-the-algebraic-regularity-lemma/), exploiting the $\ell^2$ boundedness of the discrete Hilbert transform (i.e. [Hilbert's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_inequality)), to obtain an exponential upper bound.  I don't see any obvious way to improve this to a polynomial bound (EDIT: A Whitney decomposition seems to do the trick, see below).  The argument is inspired by a stability result [of Hrushovski](http://arxiv.org/abs/0909.2190) (based on de Finetti's theorem) which shows that *some* finite bound is possible, although it is not easy to extract a quantitative bound from Hrushovski's argument (and if one did, it would surely be worse than exponential); see Proposition 2.25 of that paper.

Suppose that ${\bf P}(d_j > d_i) \geq r$ for some $r>1/2$ and all $1 \le i < j \leq k$.  Then of course 
$${\bf P}( d_j > d_i) - {\bf P}( d_j < d_i ) \geq 2r-1$$
for all $1 \le i < j \le k$.  We expand this as
$$ \sum_{1 \leq a < b \leq n} {\bf P}( d_j = b \wedge d_i = a ) - {\bf P}( d_j = a \wedge d_i = b ) \geq 2r-1.$$
Multiply by the positive quantity $\frac{1}{j-i}$ and sum to conclude that
$$ \sum_{1 \leq a < b \leq n} \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq k} \frac{1}{j-i} [{\bf P}( d_j = b \wedge d_i = a ) - {\bf P}( d_j = a \wedge d_i = b )] \gg (2r-1) k \log k \qquad (1).$$
The LHS can be rearranged as
$$ \sum_{1 \leq a < b \leq n} \sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq k: i \neq j} \frac{1}{j-i} {\bf P}(d_j = b \wedge d_i = a ) $$
and rearranged further as
$$ {\bf E} \sum_{1 \leq a < b \leq n} \sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq k: i \neq j} \frac{1}{j-i} 1_{d_j = b} 1_{d_i = a}.$$
By Hilbert's inequality, we have
$$
\sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq k: i \neq j} \frac{1}{j-i} 1_{d_j = b} 1_{d_i = a} \ll (\sum_{1 \leq j \leq k} 1_{d_j=b})^{1/2} (\sum_{1 \leq i \leq k} 1_{d_i=a})^{1/2}$$
and
$$ {\bf E} \sum_{1 \leq a < b \leq n} \sum_{1 \leq j \leq k} 1_{d_j=b}, {\bf E} \sum_{1 \leq a < b \leq n} \sum_{1 \leq i \leq k} 1_{d_i=a} \ll k n $$
so by Cauchy-Schwarz
$$
{\bf E} \sum_{1 \leq a < b \leq n} \sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq k: i \neq j} \frac{1}{j-i} 1_{d_j = b} 1_{d_i = a} \ll kn $$
and hence
$$ kn \gg (2r-1) k \log k$$
leading to the exponential upper bound
$$ k \ll \exp( O( \frac{n}{2r-1} ) ).$$

EDIT: Looks like one can improve this to the polynomial bound $k \ll n^{O(1/(2r-1))}$ using the following standard Whitney decomposition trick (used for instance to prove the Rademacher-Menshov theorem or the Christ-Kiselev lemma).  Firstly, without loss of generality we may take $n$ to be a power of 2.  Then observe that if $1 \leq a < b \leq n$, then there is a unique pair of distinct dyadic intervals $I,J$ in $\{1,\dots,n\}$ with the same parent such that $a \in I$ and $b \in J$; let's call such pairs "adjacent".  As such, the LHS of (1) can now be rearranged as

$$ {\bf E}\sum_{2^l < n} \sum_{I,J: |I|=|J|=2^l, \hbox{adjacent}}  \sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq k: i \neq j} \frac{1}{j-i} 1_J(d_j) 1_I(d_i).$$

We apply Hilbert's inequality to bound this by
$$ \pi {\bf E} \sum_{2^l < n} \sum_{I,J: |I|=|J|=2^l, \hbox{adjacent}}  (\sum_j 1_J(d_j))^{1/2} (\sum_i 1_I(d_i))^{1/2}$$
which by Cauchy-Schwarz and the disjointness of the $I,J$ can be bounded by
$$ \pi \sum_{2^l < n} k^{1/2} k^{1/2} \ll k \log n$$
leading to
$$ k \log n \gg (2r-1) k \log k $$
and thus $k \ll n^{O(1/(2r-1))}$.

Comment: Slick argument! It's nice to have a bound. For all the examples I have, Hilbert's inequality introduces almost all of the exponential slack; especially when $a$ is not close to $b$. I'm trying to think of improvements.

Comment: I think by using Hilbert's inequality more efficiently one can recover a polynomial bound; see edit.

Comment: Wow! Both Hilbert's inequality and the Whitney decomposition are new tricks for my toolbox. I am interested in bringing down the exponent, as I have numerical evidence it should be $1/r$, so I'll try various tricks (perhaps summing three terms $a<b<c$, $i<j<l$ or more instead of two?) to chisel away at this proof. I'm a lot more optimistic now than I was when I posted this.

Comment: If the $d_i$ are drawn iid from $\{1,\dots,n\}$, then $d_i \geq d_j$ with probability $1/2 - 1/2n$, regardless of how large $k$ is.  So one gets no bound on $k$ in the regime $r < 1/2 - 1/2n$.  It looks like my argument here can stretch to cover most of the regime $r \geq 1/2 - 1/2n$, by using Cauchy-Schwarz to get a nontrivial lower bound on the probability that $d_i=d_j$ on average (in the above argument this is just lower bounded by zero).

Answer (score 25):

Using Fourier analysis in the $d$ variable, we can get the optimal upper bound. As in Tao's argument, if there is a distribution of sequences for which each pair is $r$-probably increasing,  there must be a single sequence $d_i$ :
 such that:

$$\sum_{1\leq a <b \leq n} \sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq k, i\neq j} \frac{1}{j-i} 1_{d_i = a} 1_{d_j=b}  >(1+ o(1)) (2r-1) k \log k$$

We may rewrite the left hand side as:

$$\sum_{1\leq a ,b \leq n} \sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq k, i\neq j} \frac{1}{j-i} 1_{d_i = a} 1_{d_j=b} 1_{a<b}$$

Now use the "carrying the 1" decomposition:

$$ 1_{a<b} = \frac{b}{n} - \frac{a}{n} + \frac{ a-b \operatorname{mod} n}{n}$$

The first two terms are pretty simple. The first term is:

$$\sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq k, i\neq j} \frac{1}{j-i} \frac{d_j}{n} = \sum_{1 \leq j \leq k} \frac{d_j}{n} \log \left( \frac{j}{k-j} \right) \approx k $$

and the second term is similar.

Now we've replaced $1_{a<b}$ with a convolution operator. So let's take the discrete Fourier transform:

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{0 \leq \xi \leq n-1} \sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq k, i\neq j} \frac{1}{j-i} e\left( \frac{d_j \xi}{n}\right) e\left( \frac{- d_i \xi}{n}\right) \left( \sum_{x=0}^{n-1} \frac{x}{n} e \left( \frac{x \xi}{n} \right)\right)$$

By the Hilbert transform inequality:

$$\left|\sum_{1 \leq i,j \leq k, i\neq j} \frac{1}{j-i} e\left( \frac{d_j \xi}{n}\right) e\left( \frac{- d_i \xi}{n}\right)\right| \leq \pi k$$

So the bound is

$$\frac{\pi k}{n}\sum_{0 \leq \xi \leq n-1}\left| \sum_{x=0}^{n-1} \frac{x}{n} e \left( \frac{x \xi}{n} \right)\right| \approx \frac{\pi k}{n} \sum_{0 \leq \xi \leq n-1} \frac{n}{2 \pi \min(\xi,n-\xi)} \approx  k \log n$$

This gives:

$$k \log n  > (1+o(1)) (2r-1) k \log k$$

Hence:

$$n > k^{ 2r-1 +o(1) }$$

Note that the base notation trick in the original post allows us to remove the $o(1)$ in the exponent bound by amplification.

---

Here is the matching lower bound:

Suppose that I have two sequences of $k$ numbers, one of which is a sequence of numbers from $1$ to $n_1$ that is increasing with probability $r_1$, and one which is a sequence from $1$ to $n_2$ that is increasing with proobability $r_2$. For any fraction $a/b$, I can construct a sequence of $k^b$ numbers from $1$ to $n_1^a n_2^{b-a}$ that is increasing with probability $\frac{a}{b} r_1 + \frac{b-a}{b}r_2$ as follows:

Write a number from $1$ to $k^b$ in base $k$ notation as $b$ numbers from $1$ to $k$. Choose randomly $a$ of the numbers and apply the first sequence, getting a number from $1$ to $n_1$. For the rest, apply the second sequence, getting a number from $1$ to $n_2$. Encode this sequence of numbers lexicographically as a single number from $1$ to $n_1^a n_2^{b-a}$ (generalizing base notation).

For any two numbers $i$ and $j$, consider the first place where they are not equal. In that place, $j$ must be larger than $i$. $d_j$ is equal to $d_i$ in all previous places. Hence as long as $d_j> d_i$ in this place, $d_j>d_i$. The probability that it is greater in this place is at least $r_1$ if this number was chosen and $r_2$ if it wasn't, so the total probability is at least $\frac{a}{b} r_1 + \frac{b-a}{b}r_2$.

This shows that we can take $k=n^{1/f(r)}$ for a convex function $f$.  In particular, because we can take $f(1)=1$ (totally deterministic sequence) and $f(1/2-\epsilon)=0$ (totally random), we know $f(r) \leq 2r-1+\epsilon$, so we can get $k$ at least $n^{1/(2r-1)-\epsilon}$

---

An explanation of why $1/(j-i)$ is in fact the right weight function. Basically, this lower bounding method spends an equal amount of work improving the probability that $d_j>d_i$ for $j-i$ at any given scale. So the weight function should make every scale equally valuable, which $1/(j-i)$ does.

Comment: I don't understand how this can work if $l \rightarrow 0$. (I'm assuming your statement that $l$ is a natural number was a typo, since you need to let $l \rightarrow 0$ at the end.) In particular if $l$ is, say, $1/1000$, then the "gradient" of the sequence, $\alpha$, will be small, so two adjacent terms $d_i,d_{i+1}$ will be the same with large probability. In particular, when $l$ is small, the bound for the second strategy $max(1-\frac{l}{2}\frac{j-i}{n}, 1/2)-\frac{1}{l}$ has a whole $-\frac{1}{l}$ term that seems to disappear.

Comment: @LinusHamilton That's a typo. I meant to send $l$ to $|infty$, not $0$.

Comment: Ah, I see what's happening now. So $O(n^{1/r})$ is indeed wrong. Thanks, good example!

Comment: @LinusHamilton By the way, I think I know how to get up to $3/4$. I don't want to write the details right now, but the idea is that in the first sequence you add a small independent random number to each $d_i$. This means the probability that $d_j>d_i$ starts at just under $1/2$ and increases linearly to $1$. By equally averaging the two strategies, we can get a probability just  under $3/4$. This, plus Terry Tao's bound, suggests to me that the answer might be $n^{1/(2r-1)}$ exactly.

Comment: If one uses the dyadic Hilbert inequality $\sum_{I,J \hbox{ adjacent}} \sum_{i \in I} \sum_{j \in J} \frac{c_i d_j - c_j d_i}{|I|} \leq 2 (\sum_i c_i^2)^{1/2} (\sum_j d_j^2)^{1/2}$ (easiest to prove using the Haar wavelet basis) it appears that the constant $\pi \log 2$ can be reduced slightly to 2.

Comment: It may be that a Bellman function technique (yet another tool from the harmonic analysis toolbox!) may be useful in reducing the constant further, particularly if one is able to phrase the problem in a suitably "dyadic" formulation.

Comment: @TerryTao Do you think the dyadic approach is optimal? Using the usual Hilbert inequality, you can reduce the problem to a linear algebra optimization problem where, for instance, a 3-adic or 4-adic decomposition should be more efficient than 2-adic. I haven't done the exact calculations but in the case where $|\{j|d_j=d\}|$ is constant I can beat two, and that naively seems like the worst case. (By the way, it's easy to make mistakes with this kind of constant. I think it was $\pi/(2 \log 2)$ before, not $\pi \log 2$. That's still greater than )$2$, though.)

Comment: The problem I'm referring to is $\max ( \sum_{1 \leq i < j \leq n } v_i \cdot w_j)$ subject to $|v_i|=|w_i|$, $v_i \cdot v_j = w_i \cdot w_j=0$ for $i \neq j$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n |v_i|^2=1$.

Comment: In practice, dyadic arguments tend to be non-optimal by a factor of roughly 2 or so, but they have the advantage that the best constants for the dyadic version are often computable explicitly, even if they don't match the best constants for the continuous problem.  Unfortunately most of the tools in my bag of tricks aren't geared towards extracting optimal constants for continuous problems...

Comment: @TerryTao Sometimes the best constants in the continuous version are computable explicitly. : )

Comment: Nice!  I had considered using a Fourier expansion to try to diagonalise the $a < b$ constraint, but dropped the idea after seeing the $1 \leq a$ and $b \leq n$ constraints also, though the neat "carrying the 1" decomposition deals with these constraints quite elegantly.